# android recipient id doesn't return correct number

Tags: android, cursor, sms, uri, contacts

I am trying to get the contacts number by using the id from the sms-mms/conversations URI

```
final Uri URI_SIMPLE = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations").buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("simple", "true").build();
```

I am finding out though, that when I run query and it brings back a number, it is not the correct number for that id I gave.

```
public static String fetchNumberfromID(String contactID, Context c)
{
    Log.i("Utility", "*******ID********" + contactID);

    Cursor phones = c.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactID, null, null);

    //Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(phones));
    String number = null;

    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

        switch (type)
        {
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
        }
    }
    phones.close();
    return number;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The recipient_id should be the correct id that is used right? Or is there somewhere else I should be trying to get the numbers from incase they aren't stored in contacts?

Answer (score 1):

The recipient_id returned by the URI `"content://mms-sms/conversations"` correlates to the `_id` field from the relatively undocumented **canonical-addresses** table which contains phone numbers under the `address` field.

You can query for the phone numbers with an individual recipient ID like this:

```
Cursor addressCursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), null, "_id = " + recipientId, null, null);
String phoneNumber = addressCursor.getString(addressCursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
```